# I don't have Razor Editor(even though I installed mvc 3.0)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, download, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I installed mvc 3.0 in my VS 2010 and I can make and run 3.0 application but I don't get intellisense or highlighting.

It seems that I am missing the razor editor

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/snaghtml1f47de61.png

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/11/razor-intellisense-and-resharper/

Where can I download this so I can get it to work?

Comment: FWIW Resharper 5.1+ works very well with razor code files

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I uninstalled all my plugins and VS 2010. Then reinstalled VS 2010 and right after mvc 3.0. Now it works.

Comment: This answer should moved to a comment to the response from @Darin Dimitrov with his answer being accepted.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something you can download separately. It is part of the ASP.NET MVC 3.0 package. If you have downloaded it and installed it and it is still not working it is probably because it has conflicts with some other plugins you might be using such as Resharper. You may try uninstalling all third party plugins and then reinstall MVC 3.0 to see if the issue is fixed. Also you may try to reset Visual Studio environment with `devenv /resetsettings`. And IIRC there were issues with Intellisense and the C# 5.0 async CTP so if youhave this installed try removing it as well.

Comment: I will try resetting and removing 3rd party plugins(I have already removed resharper). I will try to move anhk and power pack.